# ftp client/server broken pipe error C

Tags: c, ftp

My FTP program keeps giving a Broken Pipe error and I've gone through the common reasons for that but still can't figure it out. Tried introducing some sleeptime but that caused more problems. Below is my client and server code. Any help is appreciated. Initially the error wasn't happening each run but now it is. Thank you.

ftserver.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 
#include <dirent.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>

void error(const char *msg) { perror(msg); exit(1); } // Error function used for reporting issues
void startControl(int portNo);
void setupData(char* hostname, int dataport, char* command, char* filename);
void sendDirectory();
void sendFile(char*filename);

int listenSocketFD, establishedConnectionFD, portNumber, charsRead,      charsWritten, socketFD;
socklen_t sizeOfClientInfo;
char buffer[256];
struct sockaddr_in serverAddress, clientAddress, javaAddress;
struct hostent *serverHostInfo;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {

    if (argc < 2) { fprintf(stderr,"USAGE: %s port\n", argv[0]); exit(1); }

    // Set up the address struct for the server
    memset((char *)&serverAddress, '\0', sizeof(serverAddress));
    portNumber = atoi(argv[1]);
    //signal(SIGPIPE,SIG_IGN); 
    startControl(portNumber);

    while (1){
        // Accept a connection, blocking if one is not available until one connects
        sizeOfClientInfo = sizeof(clientAddress); // Get the size of the address for the client that will connect
        establishedConnectionFD = accept(listenSocketFD, (struct sockaddr *)&clientAddress, &sizeOfClientInfo);
        if (establishedConnectionFD < 0) error("ERROR on accept");

        // Get the message from the client and display it
        memset(buffer, '\0', 256);

        printf("connection set up and ready to receive\n");
        charsRead = recv(establishedConnectionFD, buffer, 255, 0); // Read the client's message from the socket
        if (charsRead < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
        printf("SERVER: I received this from the client: \"%s\"\n", buffer);

        char *token; int dataport; char* filename; char* hostname;
        token = strtok(buffer, "#");
        if (strcmp(token, "-l") == 0){
            charsWritten = send(establishedConnectionFD, "list command", 13, 0);
            if (charsRead < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
            hostname = strtok(NULL, "#");
            printf("hostname %s\n", hostname);
            dataport = atoi(strtok(NULL, "#"));
            printf("datanum %d\n", dataport);
            //  close(establishedConnectionFD);
            filename = "";
            setupData(hostname, dataport, token, filename);
        }
        else {
            // send invalid
            charsWritten = send(establishedConnectionFD, "invalid command", 16, 0);
            if (charsRead < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
            //  close(establishedConnectionFD);     
        }

        close(establishedConnectionFD); // Close the existing socket which is connected to the client

    }

    close(listenSocketFD); // Close the listening socket
    return 0; 
    }

    void startControl(int portNo){

    // Set up the socket
    listenSocketFD = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // Create the socket
    if (listenSocketFD < 0) error("ERROR opening socket");

    serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddress.sin_port = htons(portNo);
    serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    // Enable the socket to begin listening
    if (bind(listenSocketFD, (struct sockaddr *)&serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress)) < 0) // Connect socket to port
        error("ERROR on binding");
    listen(listenSocketFD, 5); // Flip the socket on - it can now receive up to 5 connections
    printf("returning from startcontol right now\n");
}

void setupData(char* hostname, int dataport, char* command, char* filename){
// Set up the server address struct
    memset((char*)&serverAddress, '\0', sizeof(serverAddress)); // Clear out the address struct
    portNumber = dataport; // Get the port number, convert to an integer from a string
    javaAddress.sin_family = AF_INET; // Create a network-capable socket
    javaAddress.sin_port = htons(portNumber); // Store the port number
    serverHostInfo = gethostbyname(hostname); // Convert the machine name into a special form of address
    if (serverHostInfo == NULL) { fprintf(stderr, "CLIENT: ERROR, no such host\n"); exit(0); }
    memcpy((char*)&javaAddress.sin_addr.s_addr, (char*)serverHostInfo->h_addr, serverHostInfo->h_length);

    // Set up the socket
    socketFD = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // Create the socket
    if (socketFD < 0) error("CLIENT: ERROR opening socket");
    int connectionAttempts = 0; int status = 0;
    do {
        connectionAttempts++;
        status = connect(socketFD, (struct sockaddr *) &javaAddress, sizeof(javaAddress));
    } while (status == -1 && connectionAttempts < 10);
    //sleep(100);
    if (strcmp(command, "-l") == 0){
        sendDirectory();
        printf("sendDir success\n");
    }

    close(socketFD); // Close the socket

}

void sendDirectory(){
    printf("in send directory\n");
    char fileList[1000];
    memset(fileList, '\0', sizeof(fileList));

    DIR *dir = opendir(".");
    if (dir == NULL){
        perror("could not open directory");
        exit(1);
    }
    struct dirent *ent; struct stat info;
    int numFiles = 0;
    while((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        //printf("in send directory while\n");
        //printf("filename%s\n", ent->d_name);

        stat(ent->d_name, &info);   
        //skip over directories
        if (S_ISDIR(info.st_mode)){
            continue;
        }
        else if ((strcmp(ent->d_name, ".") == 0) && (strcmp(ent->d_name, "..") == 0)){
            continue;
        }
        else {
            printf("filename%s\n", ent->d_name);
            //keep adding the filenames to the filelist
            strcat(fileList, ent->d_name);
            strcat(fileList, ",");
            numFiles++;
        }

    }
    printf("fileList %s\n", fileList);
    printf("length %d\n", strlen(fileList));
    charsWritten = send(socketFD, fileList, strlen(fileList), 0);
    printf("charsWritten success\n");
        //closedir(dir);
}
```

ftclient.java

```
package ftclient;

public class Ftclientmini {

    private Socket echoSocket;
    private ServerSocket servSocket;
    private Socket dataSocket;
    PrintWriter out;
    BufferedReader in;
    PrintWriter dataOut;
    BufferedReader dataIn;
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String hostName = args[0];
        int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        String filename = ""; int datanum = 0;
        String command = args[2];
        if (command.equals("-l")){
            if (args.length != 4)
                System.err.println("Usage: java EchoClient <host name> "
                        + "<port number> <command> <dataport>");
            datanum = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
        }

        Ftclientmini one = new Ftclientmini();
        one.startControl(hostName, portNumber);
        System.out.println("have set up the control connection\n");

        one.sendCommand(command, filename, hostName, datanum);

        String servResponse = one.in.readLine();
        if (servResponse != null){
                System.out.println(servResponse);
            if (servResponse.equals("invalid command"))
                System.exit(0);
        else{
            //byte[] myarray = new byte[1024];
            String bytesRead; String[] retVal;
            one.startData(datanum);

            if (command.equals("-l")){
                while ((bytesRead = one.dataIn.readLine()) != null){
                    //bytesRead = one.dataIn.readLine();
                        retVal = bytesRead.split(",");

                    for (String temp: retVal){
                        System.out.println(temp);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
        one.servSocket.close();
        one.dataSocket.close();
        one.echoSocket.close();

        System.exit(0);

    }

    void startControl(String name, int number){
        try {
            echoSocket = new Socket(name, number);
            out = new PrintWriter(
                    echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get IO for connection to" + name);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    void sendCommand(String command, String filename, String host, int datanum){
        String stringData = Integer.toString(datanum);
        if (command.equals("-l")){
            command = command.concat("#" + host + "#" + stringData +"#");
            System.out.println("sending: " + command);
            out.println(command);
        }
        else {
            command = command.concat("#" + host + "#" + stringData + "#" + filename + "#");
            System.out.println("sending: " + command);
            out.println(command);
        }
        System.out.println("finished sending command");
    }

    void startData(int datanum){
        try {
            servSocket = new ServerSocket(datanum);
            //servSocket.setSoTimeout(10000);
            System.out.println("wait for a client");
            dataSocket = servSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("ftclient.java has been accepted");
            dataOut = new PrintWriter(
                    dataSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            dataIn = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(dataSocket.getInputStream()));

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get IO for connection");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you think asking people to plow through 250 lines of C and 150 lines of java looking for an unspecified bug is a bit of a tall order?

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See:  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](/help/mcve)"

Comment: @kuroineko don't you think providing some guidance to a beginner would not be a tall order?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thank you, I've gone through and removed the second command, just focusing on sending a directory list back from the ftserver, since it is an FTP server, I do think that both connections might need to be examined, Java is never printing it's "accepted client" message for the 2nd data connection. I've verified that the broken pipe error is still occurring.

Comment: Low hanging fruit:: `else if ((strcmp(ent->d_name, ".") == 0) && (strcmp(ent->d_name, "..") == 0)){` -->> `else if (!strcmp(ent->d_name, ".")  || !strcmp(ent->d_name, "..") ){`

Answer (score 0):

```
    int offset = 0;
    while (!feof(fp)){
        readBytes = fread(fileBuffer, 1, sizeof(fileBuffer), fp);
```

Seems like the reset of offset to zero wants to be *inside* the "while" loop...?

I assume you mean your server is receiving SIGPIPE.  Is the client still confirmed alive at that point?